# Uncaught Error: SimpleXMLElement is not properly initialized

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hello I m working on php migration from V 7.2 to 8.1 and I have an error with SimpleXMLElement :

```
$string = <<<XML
<a>
 <b>
  <c>text</c>
  <c>stuff</c>
 </b>
 <d>
  <c>code</c>
 </d>
</a>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
unset($xml[0]);

print_r(array(
    $xml,
    !empty($xml)
));
```

In php 7.2 a warning is triggered but for php 8.1 I've this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: SimpleXMLElement is not properly initialized in
```

Comment: What was the warning? What are you trying to do with this code? The `unset($xml[0]);` causes the error with the former object.

Comment: Which statement is getting that error?

Comment: @Barmar The `!empty($xml)` throws it in this block but the `$xml` usage after unsetting is the cause. https://3v4l.org/bfDv2

Comment: `$xml` is not an array, it's a `SimpleXMLElement` object. Why are you using array operations on it?

Comment: I can't find anything specific in the changelog about it, but this was implemented in [this commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/fc7bab3aee68fd7917c9fe2fd6abc2abe510e64d) as part of the wider drive in PHP 8 to upgrade internal warnings to errors ([RFC here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_warnings)). I'm not sure what you're *expecting* to happen when you run `unset($xml[0])`, but as you've said, it only ever raised a warning rather than doing anything useful. Internally, it looks like it's unsetting the reference to the root element from the object, leaving it in an unusable state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use unset to delete xml content, I found a solution it's catching php ERROR

```
$string = <<<XML
<a>
 <b>
  <c>text</c>
  <c>stuff</c>
 </b>
 <d>
  <c>code</c>
 </d>
</a>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
unset($xml[0]);

try {
    print_r(array(
       $xml,
      !empty($xml)
    ));
}catch (\Error  $e) {
    trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_WARNING);
    // do someting
}
```